# how to get the value of visualforce component into apex controller

Tags: apex, visualforce

I would like to access the Visualforce page component value into apex controller. I have tried it but not able to achieve can anyone tell.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to show what you have tried. Also, take a moment to visit the [help] and read [ask]. And it wouldn't hurt to look at [sscce](http://www.sscce.org).

Comment: see https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Controller_Component_Communication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like below in the VF page

```
<apex:param name="test" value="XYZ" assingTo={!valForController}/>
```

and the controller code will be like

```
public string valForController {get;set;}
```